# How to fine tune AWS R4 Aurora MySql database

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, innodb, amazon-aurora

I have a database currently at 6.5Gb but growing fast...

Currently on a R4L Aurora server, 15.25G Ram, 2 core CPU

I am looking at buying a Reserved Instance to cut costs, but worried that if the database grows fast, e.g. reaches over 15G within a year, I'll need to get a bigger server.

99% of the data is transactional history, this table is the biggest by far. It is written very frequently, but once a row has been written it doesn't change often (although it does on occasion).

So few questions...

1) Should I disable the cache?

2) Will I be ok with 15G ram, even if the database itself goes to (say) 30G, or will I see massive speed issues

3) The database is well indexed, but could this be improved? E.g. if (say) 1 million records belong to 1 user, is there a way to partition the data to prevent that slowing down access for other users?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

- "Should I disable the cache?" -- Which "cache"?
- "will I see massive speed issues" -- We need to see the queries, etc.
- "The database is well indexed" -- If that means you indexed every column, then it is not well indexed.  Please show us `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and a few of the important queries.
- "partition" -- With few exceptions, partitioning does *not* speed up MySQL tables.  Again, we need details.
- "15.25G Ram" & "database...15G" -- It is quite common for the dataset size to be bigger, even *much* bigger, than RAM.  So, this pair of numbers are not necessarily good to compare to each other.
- "1 million records belong to 1 user" -- Again, details, please.

Answer (score 0):

You should statistically explain the data growth. This can be done by running a count(*) query group by created date (year) column. Once you have a count of records per year then you can understand what's going on.

**Now you can think of possible solutions**

1. You can remove data which is no longer relevant from history standpoint and keep the storage limited.
2. If there's large amount of data e.g. Blob etc. possibly you can target storing that in S3 and store reference into database table
3. Delete any unwanted tables. Sometimes DBA creates temporary backup tables and they leave them there after work. You can clean such tables.

Answer (score 0):

The memory of the instance just comes into play when the engine fetches pages into the buffer pool for page misses. It does not depend on your actual data size (except in extreme cases, for example, your records are really really huge). The rule of thumb is to make sure you always keep your working set warm in the buffer pool, and avoid pages getting flushed.

If your app does need to touch a large amount of data, then the ideal way to do that would be to have dedicated replicas for specific kinds of queries. That way, you avoid swapping out valid pages in favor of newer queries. Aurora has custom endpoints support now, and that makes this even easier to manage.

If you need more specific guidelines, you may need to share details about your data, indices, queries etc.